# Trying to figure out why my contact form isn't working

Tags: php, contact-form

Ok so I have a contact.php form, which I have used in the past but for some reason I't wont work with a new template I am working on. I'm hoping someone can help point out what I'm not seeing. The template itself is using bootstrap. Apologies for asking but its driving me mad lol

HTML FORM

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
    <div class="form__inner">
        <div class="form__group form__column">
            <input type="text" class="form__element field" name="username" placeholder="Your name" pattern="^\S[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\s]+\S" required="required" data-error="Please enter your name"> <i class="icon form__icon icon-user"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form__group form__column">
            <input type="email" class="form__element field" name="usermail" placeholder="Your email" required="required" data-error="Please enter a valid e-mail"> <i class="icon form__icon icon-envelope"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <select class="form__element select" name="subject">
            <option class="select__option">Subject</option>
            <option class="select__option">Job</option>
            <option class="select__option">Digital Marketing Workshop</option>
            <option class="select__option">Testimonial</option>
            <option class="select__option">Other</option>
        </select><i class="icon form__icon icon-book"></i></div>
    <div class="form__group">
        <textarea class="form__element field textarea" name="msg" placeholder="Your message" required="required" data-error="Please leave a message"></textarea><i class="icon form__icon icon-bubbles"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></div>
    <div class="form__button-box">
        <button class="button">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Contact.php

```
<?php

// configure
$from = 'Support <test@test.com>'; 
$sendTo = 'Sales <test@test.com>';
$subject = 'I would like to arrange a FREE quotation';
$fields = array('username' => 'username', 'usermail' => 'usermail' , 'subject' => 'subject' , 'msg' => 'msg'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, we will get back to you soon!';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help with this guys, battling the flu atm and currently a bit out of it lol

Comment: what error are you getting? and what is this "catch (\Exception $e)" ? what is the "\" doing there?

Comment: It would be helpful to share the actual error message, or at least a description of the problem you see when you say it "won't work".

Comment: Are you even submitting the form? I only see a <button class="button">, should be a controller behind it

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile `\` we use this to reference items from global scope nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Your Form is working see image, just few things you need to fix, First your button must have a name attribute then on your controller check if the button is set before sending the form, it might happen your were sending empty form.

page.php

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">
<div class="form__inner">
    <div class="form__group form__column">
        <input type="text" class="form__element field" name="username" placeholder="Your name" pattern="^\S[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z\s]+\S" required="required" data-error="Please enter your name"> <i class="icon form__icon icon-user"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form__group form__column">
        <input type="email" class="form__element field" name="usermail" placeholder="Your email" required="required" data-error="Please enter a valid e-mail"> <i class="icon form__icon icon-envelope"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form__group">
    <select class="form__element select" name="subject">
        <option class="select__option">Subject</option>
        <option class="select__option">Job</option>
        <option class="select__option">Digital Marketing Workshop</option>
        <option class="select__option">Testimonial</option>
        <option class="select__option">Other</option>
    </select><i class="icon form__icon icon-book"></i></div>
<div class="form__group">
    <textarea class="form__element field textarea" name="msg" placeholder="Your message" required="required" data-error="Please leave a message"></textarea><i class="icon form__icon icon-bubbles"></i> <span class="form__decor-line"></span></br><div class="help-block with-errors"></div></div>
<div class="form__button-box">
    <button class="button" name="send">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
// configure
$from = 'Support <test@test.com>'; 
$sendTo = 'Sales <test@test.com>';
$subject = 'I would like to arrange a FREE quotation';
$fields = array('username' => 'username', 'usermail' => 'usermail' , 'subject' => 'subject' , 'msg' => 'msg'); // array variable name => Text to appear in email
$okMessage = '';
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// let's do the sending
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

try
{
    $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, "From: " . $from);
    $okMessage="Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, we will get back to you soon!";
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}

}


?>
```

**Results:**

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efqzP.jpg)

**NB: You also need to validate your fieds man, not with the html5 buildin required fields use your own validations, html5 does'nt correctly verify emails.**